# Slider skips one slide while clicking next/prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two challenges building my own carousel.

## 1 When you click to the next or previous button (in my case it's the black box) it skips one slide.

Please check this fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/k1ea93xt/3/

Simply, when you click next or prev only, it works good, but when you change your mind and hit the other one, the problem occurs.

Generally, I think I know what is the cause. I add class "out" to the next slider to launch the animation

```
$('.nxt').addClass('out');
```

and "in" - reversed animation to the previous slider

```
$('.prv').addClass('in');
```

Both "in" and "out" remains in the current slider which destroys the translateX value.

## 2 Second issue is I change sliders by changing classes nxt, prv and current (my js skills are limited)

```
$('.nxt').addClass('out');
$('.current').removeClass('out');
$('.prv').removeClass('out');

$('.t1').removeClass('current');
$('.t2').removeClass('nxt');
$('.t3').removeClass('prv');

$('.t1').addClass('prv');
$('.t2').addClass('current');
$('.t3').addClass('nxt');

$('.current').removeClass('t2');
$('.prv').removeClass('t1');
$('.nxt').removeClass('t3');

$('.current').addClass('t1');
$('.nxt').addClass('t2');
$('.prv').addClass('t3');

$('.t1').removeClass('in');
$('.t2').removeClass('in');
$('.t3').removeClass('in');
```

The problem is I can't have more than 3 slides in the carousel. Is there a simple way to assign classes current, prv and nxt automatically?
Thx in advance.

Comment: I would be happy even to detect the next and previous div in the main-slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your jQuery and created a function to find next and previous slides and added some setTimeout(). this will allow you to have as many slides as you want.

I have also moved the slider buttons outside of the slider as the function look for elements inside .main-slider

```js
    var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(getNext, 1000); // milliseconds
    $('.next').on('click', getNext);
    $('.previous').on('click', getPrev);
});
//Get next slide
function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.main-slider .slide.current'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.main-slider .slide').first();
    transitionOut($curr, $next);
}

// get previous
function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.main-slider .slide.current'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.main-slider .slide').last();
    transitionIn($curr, $next);
}
//slide in
function transitionIn($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);
        $curr.css('z-index', 0).removeClass('current');
        $next.show().css('z-index', 1).addClass('in').addClass('current');
        $next.children().addClass('in');
          setTimeout(function(){
            $curr.hide();
            $next.removeClass('in');
            $next.children().removeClass('in');
          },1000)
        

}
//slide out
function transitionOut($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);
        $curr.css('z-index', 1).addClass('out').removeClass('current');
        $next.show().css('z-index', 0).addClass('current');
        $curr.children().addClass('out');
         setTimeout(function(){
            $curr.hide();
            $curr.removeClass('out');
            $curr.children().removeClass('out');
          },1000)
    }
```

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    }
/*slider*/
.main-slider {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-slider .cover {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.main-slider img {
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute !important;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.cropped-image{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.slide.in {
  z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(-0%);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms; 
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-name: slide-in;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1); /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1);
}
.cropped-image.in {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms; 
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide-in-b; 
    animation-name: slide-in-b;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1); /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1);

}

.slide.out {
    transform: translateX(-0%);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms; 
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-name: slide-in;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1); /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1);
}
.cropped-image.out {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms; 
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide-in-b; 
    animation-name: slide-in-b;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1); /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.82,0,.19,1);
}
@keyframes slide-in {
    0%   {transform: translateX(-0%);}
    100%  {transform: translateX(-100%);}
}

@keyframes slide-in-b {
    0%   {transform: translateX(0%);}
    100%  {transform: translateX(100%);}
}
.next {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    background: #141212;
    width: 80px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    z-index: 9;
}
.previous {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    background: #141212;
    width: 80px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    z-index: 9;
}
/* end of slider*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next"></div>
    <div class="previous"></div>
<div class="main-slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <figure class="cropped-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508108712903-49b7ef9b1df8?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" class="cover">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <figure class="cropped-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507980668227-a52aa457699b?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" class="cover">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <figure class="cropped-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497030855747-0fc424f89a4b?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" class="cover">
      </figure>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have just updated the fiddle as your transition were a bit different - https://fiddle.jshell.net/Jim_Miraidev/xjLr1a18/

Comment: Thanks so much for working on this. Yeah, I wanted to achieve a similar transition (animation) to this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/k1ea93xt/19/  In your fiddle there is one stage when all three images have display:none

Comment: Here is the actual result https://fiddle.jshell.net/k1ea93xt/10/  still the animation for the next slider is different

Comment: Oh I see! Outstanding!! Thanks man so much! There is one issue still, images blink sometimes, but I can't belive it works!

Comment: The code above should do the trick,as your fiddle is starting to get a bit confusing with all the different classes. I would advise you to use the functions above as it keep the whole slider cleaner. Because you are using CSS transitions and they aren't finished before the next click transition.